# Kivy: Odd label spacing in GridLayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, python-3.6, kivy-language

I'm making a webscraper that would take articles from different websites. To do this, I dynamically added the article widgets to their respective GridLayouts. However, some screens have articles that are evenly spaced out, while others will be spaced sporadically. It seems like the longer the article is, the less space there is. Below are the snippets of my code that I thought were relevant (I would include everything but it's 1300+ lines).

Examples:

Good spacing
[image: Good spacing]

Bad spacing
[image: Bad spacing]

Python:

```
def text_collision(self):
    labels = [i for i in self.news_articles.children]
    for label in labels:
        font_instance = 35
        label.size = label.texture_size
        if label.collide_point(*label.to_widget(*Window.mouse_pos)):
            animation = Animation(font_size=font_instance + 2, s=1 / 60, duration=.06)
            label.color = (.96, .60, .61, 1)
            if label.count == 0:
                animation.start(label)
                label.count += 1
        else:
            label.count = 0
            Animation.cancel_all(label)
            label.color = (1, 1, 1, 1)
            label.font_size = font_instance

def articles(self):
    titles = self.csv_load()[0]
    links = self.csv_load()[1]
    for lnk, items in zip(links, titles):
        if len(items.strip()) == 0 or len(lnk.strip()) == 0:
            continue
        article_widget = Label(text="[ref={}][b]{}[/b][/ref]".format(lnk, items), markup=True, 
                         font_size=35, text_size=(700, None), halign='left', size_hint_y=None)
        self.news_articles.add_widget(article_widget)
        article_widget.on_ref_press = self.openlink
```

Kivy:

```
ScrollView:
    do_scroll_x: False
    do_scroll_y: True
    pos: (50, -140)
    smooth_scroll_end: 5

    GridLayout:
        id: articles
        cols: 1
        col_default_width: 700
        padding: [0, 140, 0, 0]
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        spacing: 150
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried for hours and still couldn't find a reasonable solution so I came up with a bit of a scuffed answer. All I did was limit the amount of characters based on the len of the article titles. This way the spacing was less sporadic since all the widgets were more or less the same height.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `height: self.minimum_height` in the `GridLayout`, you must have well defined `heights` for the children. So `size_hint_y=None` without providing a value for `height` will cause problems. Try creating a `kv` rule for an `Aricle_Widget` like this:

```
class Article_Widget(Label):
    pass
```

And in the `kv`:

```
<Article_Widget>:
    markup: True
    font_size: 35
    text_size: (700, None)
    halign: 'left'
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
```

Then in your `articles()` method:

```
article_widget = Article_Widget(text="[ref={}][b]{}[/b][/ref]".format(lnk, items))
```

I haven't tested this code, so I can't guarantee that it will work. But the idea is to have the `Label` determine its `height`, so that the `GridLayout` can correctly calculate `self.minimum_height`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! While this specific code didn't work perfectly, I can definitely tweak it now that I actually understand what's wrong.